# How to make grids different in GridBagLayout in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, gridbaglayout

what I want to achieve is something like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
JDialog messageDialog = new JDialog();
messageDialog.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
messageDialog.setBounds(0, 0, 350, 250);
messageDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
messageDialog.setVisible(true);

JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel clearPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel labelsPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel txtPanel = new JPanel();
JButton newMessage = new JButton("New");
JButton recievedMessages = new JButton("Recieved");
JButton sendMessages = new JButton("Sent");
JButton refreshMessages = new JButton("Refresh");
JLabel recievedMessLab = new JLabel("Messages get:");
JTextPane txtToSend = new JTextPane();

btnPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
btnPanel.add(newMessage);
btnPanel.add(recievedMessages);
btnPanel.add(sendMessages);
btnPanel.add(refreshMessages);

c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
messageDialog.add(clearPanel, c);

c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 0;
messageDialog.add(labelsPanel, c);

c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 1;
messageDialog.add(btnPanel, c);

c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 1;
messageDialog.add(txtPanel, c);

labelsPanel.add(recievedMessLab);
```

I don't know why I get some free space around all the panels and I can't figure out how to resize the grids. Oracle tutorial doesn't help too. What is the easiest way to resize this? How to rid of that free space?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add *weight* and *fill* information to your `GridBagConstraints` so the layout manager knows which components to strech over the available space.

Try the following:

```
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
c.fill = c.NONE;  // dont fill (strech)
messageDialog.add(clearPanel, c);

c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 0;
c.weightx = 1; // horizontal weight: 1
c.fill = c.HORIZONTAL; // fill (strech) horizontally
messageDialog.add(labelsPanel, c);

c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 1;
c.weightx = 0; // horizontal weight: back to 0
c.weighty = 1; // vertical weight: 1
c.fill = c.VERTICAL; // fill (strech) vertically
messageDialog.add(btnPanel, c);

c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 1;
c.weightx = 1; // both weights: 1
c.weighty = 1; // both weights: 1
c.fill = c.BOTH; // and fill both ways, vertically and horizontally
messageDialog.add(txtPanel, c);
```

Revisit the part about `weightx`, `weighty` and `fill` in the tutorial to get a clue how they work.

PS: `txtPanel` is empty and `txtToSend` is never used?